# How do I remove the gap between div tags?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div id='social'>
<img src="twitter.png"  alt="Twitter"/>
</div>

<h1>Heading</h1>
```

I would like the image to sit directly on top of the heading so I used:

```
margin-top: -25px;
```

This displays correctly in Chrome and Safari. In firefox however the head and image overlap. With a bit of playing around it seems that Chrome and Safari create an empty space between the divs.

How do I arrange my page/css so that it displays without a space between the image and heading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `<h1>` tag with built-in margins.  lol~  Style the `<h1>` tag with `margin:0px; padding:0px;`

Comment: I've already tried this but it totally messes with I already have. It would read like this if I put it all together http://pastebin.com/31HMFgF8

Comment: Well in the example you linked, you are putting the margin:0px; padding:0px; at the bottom which is overriding your left and right margin of auto.  Put the 0px line above the auto lines and see if that gives you what you need.  If now, what is it doing that you don't want it to do?

Comment: messes with other H1 tags?  Give it an ID and use that.

Comment: There is still a clear difference between spacing in the different browsers. Grr..

Comment: @Sheldon Other than the blue outline around the image (should style it with `border:0px; outline:0px;`), everything looks the same.

Comment: @Sheldon Yes, that's what it looks like to me, besides IE putting that outline around it.

Comment: Perhaps we are getting a little bit sidetracked? The blue bird does not sit on the 'R' as it does in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the bird was off like that.  Here's what I see in firefox.  http://i205.photobucket.com/albums/bb198/jamesnjewell/bird.png

Answer (score 1):

James is right - the  tags have margins by default, *which also vary between browsers. You can either override them all, or use a CSS reset such as [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) that will clear all default browser CSS styles so you can define them from scratch yourself.

I can almost guarantee that if you'll end up having spacing issues with CSS on any bigish project, it'll be the lack of a reset :)

Also know that browsers parse tabs and newlines as whitespace - and there's little you can do about it. If you have horizontal elements on your web page that are on newlines in the source, they'll be separated by a space (sometimes this isn't what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help:

```
#social img { display: block; }
```

or

```
#social img { vertical-align: top; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9z6BM/1/